# Video frame events fire faster than can be processed

Tags: c#, .net, events, image-processing

I am having an issue with my vision processing code. I wish there was an actual error that would point me in the right direction and that I could share with all of you. However, there is no error per se. The thing I am getting is unintentional side effects in my video.

I have an IP network camera that is streaming H.264 video on the network. It is set to do this at 20 fps, though I have tried turning it down to 15 fps. Not sure if I want or need to go lower than that.

I am reading the frames in my code just fine. The way I have it integrated now is I get an event that raises every time there is a new frame from the camera, in my case 15 to 20 times per second.

I am trying to process that video frame as quickly as possible but I am doing some OpenCV (or better EmguCV) processing on it along with some object tracking.

Because I am object tracking, i can just ignore or dump frames in between because having them in order/sequential is important.

My processing time fluctuates but can be slower at times but only by a few frames, like 3 to 4 frames. However, when I am slower, I naturally miss frames and this causes the object tracker to drop tracking and the video to appear like it is skipping, both of which I dont want.

Aside from seeing if I can speed up my processing, which I may not be able to do, what is the best way to handle this so I dont skip or drop frames that fire and come in even though I am still processing or processing a little slower?

I am looking in to a concurrent queue to act as a buffer but i am not sure if going down this road is the right approach either.

Thanks!!

Comment: If processing is slower them your frame rate then your only options are. A) Make your code more efficient B) Drop frames C) Buffer them (however if this goes on for too long you could be run out of memory or increase massive work loads that never get done, However i am guessing you know all this

Comment: Thank you @TheGeneral yeah, I figured those were my options. I dont have much control over A because I am using mostly EmguCv calls and have ensured my PC is as capable as possible (GPU and Cuda). Maybe I can drop frames in a controlled and consistent manner so the tracking doesnt freak out. Otherwise I guess I am looking at a buffer and just limit the size of it to prevent memory issues.